# for loop on NodeList no longer works in playframework 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, xmlnodelist

This Code worked in play framework 2.0.4

```
@defining(XPath.selectNodes("root/modules", xDoc)){modules=>    
  @for(module <- modules){
    <div class="heading">@module.fullName()</div>
    <!-- More processing code -->
  }
}
```

But no longer works in play 2.1.1

The error displayed is that the for loop cannot iterate over a NodeList. I guess, something has changed in scala from the previous version. As a workaround, I used [this code](http://odoepner.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/turn-org-w3c-dom-nodelist-into-iterable/) to convert the NodeList object to iterable but it still fails

[image: Error]

I would appreciate if you can explain the reason for this error and possible fixes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `@for(module <- modules)` ???

Comment: you are right. it was a typo. corrected it in the question

Comment: Please don't ever post error messages in an image.

Comment: ok..any particular reason?

Comment: @rusticbit: Text in images isn't going to get indexed by search engines, so someone looking for discussions of the same error message won't be able to find this question. It also breaks accessibility unnecessarily—it's not likely to work well in screen readers, for example. Also it's just ugly.